# Open PWA-framed window from Chrome from Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a PWA that is able to open secondary windows, when I open them using `window.open` the new windows have the same window style of the main PWA (no Chrome UI, no tabs, no address bar, status bar of the color defined by my app), the new window will also be grouped under the PWA icon in the operative system Dock/taskbar.

The look of the windows is just like the image below:

[image]

I also have a Chrome extension that must be able to open such windows, but the problem I'm having is that if I use `chrome.windows.create` with `popup` type the resulting windows have the normal Chrome status bar color, and they aren't listed under the PWA icon. Like this:

[image]

I'd like to understand if there's any way to open a window from a Chrome extension and have it follow the PWA-defined theme and get listed under the PWA dock/taskbar icon?

Comment: I linked the wrong method, sorry T_T.

Answer (score 1):

To launch an installed PWA use [chrome.management](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/management/) API in an extension page or background script:

```js
chrome.management.getAll(apps => {
  const pwa = apps.find(a => a.appLaunchUrl === 'https://pwa.foo.bar/');
  if (pwa) chrome.management.launchApp(pwa.id);
});
```

If you want to set the [launch type](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/management/#type-LaunchType):

```js
chrome.management.getAll(apps => {
  for (const a of apps) {
    if (a.appLaunchUrl === 'https://pwa.foo.bar/') {
      chrome.management.setLaunchType(a.id, 'OPEN_AS_WINDOW', () => {
        chrome.management.launchApp(a.id);
      });
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

**manifest.json:**

```json
{
  "permissions": ["management"],
```

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't allow to specify the pathname that I want to open though, is there any way to specify it?

Comment: No, you'll have to use chrome.tabs.update or a content script inside the PWA to change the URL.

Comment: This  seems to only list very few pre installed apps not self installed pwa apps. Does it need extra permission to list all user installed pwa apps ?

Comment: It may be a bug in Chrome or they've removed this functionality.

Comment: @wOxxOm Unfortunately it seems this feature has never worked for the past few years. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1263843 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=956967 Do you have any suggestions for alternatives? Thanks!